# How is message sequence preserved for topic with many partitions?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I want any information/explanation on how Kafka maintains a message sequence when messages are written to topic with multiple partition.
For e.g. I have multiple message producer each producing messages sequentially and writing on the Kafka topic with more than 1 partition. In this case, how consumer group will work to consume messages.

Answer (score 6):

Kafka only provides a total order over records **within** a partition, not between different partitions in a topic. Even within one partition, you still could encounter the out-of-order events if retries is enabled and *max.in.flight.requests.per.connection* is larger than 1.

Work-around is create a topic with only one partition although it means only one consumer process per consumer group.

Answer (score 5):

Kafka will store messages in the partitions according to the message key given to the producer. If none is given, then the messages will be written in a round-robin style into the partitions. To keep ordering for a topic, you need to make sure the ordered sequence has the same key, or that the topic has only one partition.

Comment: Thank you for the reply So how does consumer group work in this case how do they manage offset, let assume I am sending 13 messages with no key to a topic that has 5 partitions, If I am not wrong then message distribution will more or less same as 3 messages-Part1, 3 messages-Part2, 3 messages-Part3, 2 messages-Part4, 2 messages-Part5.

Comment: The guarantee you get from Kafka, is that every message in every partition will be sent to only one consumer in every group. Each consumer in the group is assigned some of the partitions, and will get the messages that are sent to it.
So, to take the example you gave, if the consumer group had, say, two consumers in it, one might get partitions 1-3, and the other partitions 4-5.
The first consumer will then be getting 9 messages, and the second 4 messages.

Comment: taking the above example as you said we have 2 consumer in a consumer group one consumer gets partition 1-3 and other partition 4-5, if I add one spark streaming direct api consumer to the same consumer group, In what mechanism this consumer's will help to read data for spark streaming.